# Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $f(r)=0$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $f=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continuity

Here's my proof for it:

It has been given that $f(r)=0$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, so it remains to shows that $f(z)=0$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. So, let $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of rationals such that $\lim x_n = z$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $\lim f(x_n) = 0 = f(z)$. Since, $z$ was arbitrary, it is true for all irrationals.

Is this proof okay? It feels a little strange to me since I've cherry picked a sequence which forces $f(z)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof seems fine.

You might want to state that you have used density of rational number explicitly.

Comment: Here's a question: Why do I need to mention that explicitly? Is it because we need the density of rationals to find such a sequence?

Comment: Let $x_n$ be a rational sequence that converges to $z$, I was just thinking how do you justify the existence of such a sequence. One possible explaination is you can get if from the density of rational numbers. Alternatively, perhaps look at the decimal number expansion.

Comment: i guess if for each $n$ we pick $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $z-\frac{1}{n} < x_n < z$, then by the squeeze theorem, $\lim x_n = z$. I think this will do it. It implicitly uses the density of rationals.